# No repetir número aleatorio sobre una matriz

Tags: java, java-8

Tengo una duda sobre no repetir los números aleatorios realizando una matriz.

He utilizado una matriz y recorriendo con un bucle *for*, llamando con un *math.random* para sacar los números aleatorios.

También he usado una ordenación de números aleatorios, todo esto funciona correctamente, pero realmente lo que me falta es que no se repita.

```
public static void numeroAleatorio() {
    //matriz1, 1 fila de 5 nº
    int[][] matriz1= new int[1][5];
    //matriz2, 1 fila de 2 nº
    int [][] matriz2 = new int [1][2];
        
    //recorremos y sacamos nº hasta el 50
    for (int x=0; x < matriz1.length; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y < matriz1[x].length; y++) {
            matriz1[x][y] = (int) (Math.random()*49+1);
        }
        //recorremos y sacamos nº hasta el 12  
        for (int a = 0; a < matriz2.length; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < matriz2[a].length; b++) {
                matriz2[a][b] = (int) (Math.random()*12+1);
            }
        }      
    }
    // ordenamos los numeros de menor a mayor 
    for (int[] x : matriz1) {
        Arrays.sort(x);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
    }
    // ordenamos los numeros de menor a mayor 
    for(int[] w : matriz2) {
        Arrays.sort(w);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(w));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias apoyarte en el uso de un ArrayList y su método [contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))...junto con un bucle do while. La lógica sera que mientras  el Arraylist contenga un numero aleatorio ya generado se repita el bucle hasta generar un numero que no este incluido en el Arraylist y de esta manera se asigne a una posición nueva del arraybidimensional y a su vez sea agrege al arrayList para que solo se guarden numero aleatorios no repetidos,los cuales serán asignados al array bidimensional

ejemplo

```
public static void numeroAleatorio() {
   //Declara un arrayList 
        ArrayList<Integer>lista=new ArrayList<>();

        int num=0;

        int[][] matriz1= new int[1][5];
      
        
        //recorremos y sacamos nº hasta el 50
        for (int x=0; x < matriz1.length; x++) {
            
              for (int y=0; y < matriz1[x].length; y++) {
                    
                   do{ 
                    //generamos el numero aleatorio
                     num = (int) (Math.random()*49+1);
                    //asignamos a matriz
                     matriz1[x][y]=num;
                   //si lista contiene a ese numero se repite el buble
                   }while(lista.contains(num));
                  //si la lista no contiene a ese numero lo agrega
                   lista.add(num);     
                 
              }
          }
```

[**TEST**](https://tio.run/##pVVNj5swED3Dr5gjNC27WM2hZbPSHit1T3tEHJzgTUiNHdnOJnTFH@uxfywdEwIkMdVq10ICD2@e/eb5Y01f6Jd1/utwKMqNVAbWGIi2puDRg1K00onv/vGz0Cbx/c12zosFLDjVGh5pIV5938OnjWtDDb5eZJGD2JZMyQfOqJGqkEEIFut1bHc/hGFLpu45duhMsB30/@6DMBkHExca4YUwdtjZbdJ3iO3d3JTUqOJ3/BlieC44hZzBFMTfPz60DeFplmbQAmdgh7DBOEunWdLhTlRkSEUuqWDARaAjA8tGBmwDWsUWUilWSg0VaLqg9gtpYUVRMjAO09sO/iwVBJZwj/JgD3eneUeciaVZYWwysRWHQTvrDDgqy1H1HOk@62iqa5oRuqbl8tUZB2sF1sGOF0LwSM0qUlTksgzCT1@/TeIwcaf1U0qrbIYkTly9WxWcBc3iiBZSGFyZOkB06OY9AmmeN5hkRM5FpPaH32c/3@JeTC4ZOwMoVgYtoJ0FpKs/dde/S50fU@d9akp79@bubA9tug56zW5xOhSTcYc6k@zI6TwD6xJJ/OsBhi6RM5uIyyevBbY2EQekPovU4@tyuNFAqpyJxiBuTWrOKW23cckE1pWingrfo0XHnb2H76elObY9judppPEwDfYjxXuqtGFlJLcm2ihk5iJo04x8QnaxxNT/6/6YnlbOrpND3iJn9345O7cc/6LrulBKXC3BkQanTNVSt1fK1U1jj3/fq/36cPgH)

Comment: gracias por el ejemplo, todo entendido

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar listas para hacerlo de una forma mas sencilla. Para ello puedes crear una lista que contenga el rango de los valores aleatorios que tienes y luego ir sacándolos de forma aleatoria y introduciendo los en otra lista o donde irán los valores aleatorios.

```java
        // 1 - 500
        final List<Integer> range = IntStream.range(1, 11).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        final List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<>();
        final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final int index = random.nextInt(range.size());
            randomList.add(range.remove(index));
        }

        System.out.println(randomList);
```

Comment: Si, cierto. No sabía si meter la matriz en una lista o si se puede sacar directamente con la matriz.. Muchas gracias